Picker doesn't show options in macOS from a MAUI project
In my .NET8 MAUI project, I have a Picker with a few options: it works for every other system but not for macOS. Just to give you complete info, the Picker is in a popup from the Community Toolkit. I saw other similar posts like:

GitHub
Stackoverflow

I saw a possible solution if your Picker has a title but, in my case, I don't have the title.
<Picker
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceConnections}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConnection}"
    TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
    TitleColor="LightGray"
    Title="{OnPlatform iOS='Select an environment...',
                       Android='Select an environment...',
                       WinUI='Select an environment...'}" />

In my case, I have a simple PIcker with a binding from the ViewModel. The picker s working for Windows, iOS and Android.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup
    x:Class="PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.LanguagePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:md="clr-namespace:PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.Models"
    xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Name="popupLanguage">

    <toolkit:Popup.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type popups:LanguagePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </toolkit:Popup.Resources>

    <Grid
        Padding="5"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid
                Margin="10,0,10,0"
                ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <SearchBar
                    x:Name="searchBar"
                    Margin="0,0,5,5"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Placeholder="Search"
                    TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Picker
                    x:Name="pickerFilter"
                    Grid.Column="1" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
                    SelectedIndexChanged="pickerFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Grid>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Margin="10,25,10,10"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsEmpty}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Source="nodata.png"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    WidthRequest="30" />
                <Label
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Text="No data for this selection"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="End" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>

        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <!-- more controls -->
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</toolkit: Popup>

When I click on the Picker, nothing is displayed.

May I ask what CommunityToolkit version do you use?

CommunityToolkit.MAUI 9.0.3 - CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.2.2 - Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.82 - Microsoft.Maui.Contrls.Compatibility 8.0.82

When I downgrade to CommunityToolkit 8.0.1, there seems no issue.(may be a workaround). You may follow up this GitHub issue.
